# JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting my JSON string as:

```
newStr = { total:"1", page:"1", records:"2", rows: [<li>a</li><li>b</li>] }.
jQuery("#list").addJSONData(JSON.parse(newStr));
```

Comment: `newStr` appears to already be an object, not a string, hence why `JSON.parse` is throwing an error. You can remove that method call.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse something that is not a string. This will implicitly call `toString` on the object, and you get the string `[object Object]`, which is not valid JSON.

Either parse a string:

```
newStr = '{"total":"1","page":"1","records":"2","rows":["<li>a</li>", "<li>b</li>"]}';
jQuery("#list").addJSONData(JSON.parse(newStr));
```

or use the object:

```
newStr = { total:"1", page:"1", records:"2", rows: ["<li>a</li>", "<li>b</li>"] };
jQuery("#list").addJSONData(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying put a json data as Json data,remove **JSON.parse** it will work