# Error when loading GeoJSON to OpenLayers 3 VectorLayer: JSON.parse expected property name

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers-3, geojson

I'm trying to load a GeoJSON string into a VectorLayer but facing a `JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data` problem.

Already read som texts about like [JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601902/json-parse-expected-property-name-or-at-line-1-column-2-of-the-json-data) but can't solve my problem.

This is my JSON. Tested at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection','crs': {'type': 'name','properties': {'name': 'EPSG:4326'}},'features': [{'type': 'Feature','geometry':{'type':'MultiLineString','coordinates':[[[-43.1996056,-22.9109588],[-43.1993777,-22.9115575],[-43.1993539,-22.9116778],[-43.1993568,-22.9118156],[-43.199378,-22.9123812]]]}},{'type': 'Feature','geometry':{'type':'MultiLineString','coordinates':[[[-43.199378,-22.9123812],[-43.1994332,-22.9131767]]]}},{'type': 'Feature','geometry':{'type':'MultiLineString','coordinates':[[[-43.1994332,-22.9131767],[-43.1994563,-22.9141351],[-43.1994364,-22.9142456],[-43.199379,-22.9143303]]]}},{'type': 'Feature','geometry':{'type':'MultiLineString','coordinates':[[[-43.199379,-22.9143303],[-43.1985846,-22.9144791]]]}}]}
```

My OpenLayers stuff (`featuresText` is the GeoJSON above):

```
    var styleFunction = function(feature) {
        return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    };      

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: ( new ol.format.GeoJSON() ).readFeatures( featuresText )
    });     

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: styleFunction
    });
```

Error is at `ol-debug.js:45632`. The JSON string seems to be ok. I can't figure out.

I've read this http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html too.

Comment: Why here and not in GIS? I think it is a JSON formating problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your geojson and your error message, I'll try an answer. Line one column 2 is a single quotation. JSON requires double quotes to hold strings, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote).

Also, from the [geojson specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects):

> A feature object must have a member with the name "properties". The value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null value).

Your features have no properties.

With those two changes:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name","properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}},"features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {}, "geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-43.1996056,-22.9109588],[-43.1993777,-22.9115575],[-43.1993539,-22.9116778],[-43.1993568,-22.9118156],[-43.199378,-22.9123812]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {}, "geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-43.199378,-22.9123812],[-43.1994332,-22.9131767]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {}, "geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-43.1994332,-22.9131767],[-43.1994563,-22.9141351],[-43.1994364,-22.9142456],[-43.199379,-22.9143303]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {}, "geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-43.199379,-22.9143303],[-43.1985846,-22.9144791]]]}}]}
```

I had your geojson display successfully at [geojson.io](http://geojson.io)

Comment: Great. I've found  someone saying just the opposite. JSON must be single quoted. I think the problem may be just the `properties` member. Will try it now and post the results.

Comment: You're right. All is working fine now (well, I'm facing some problems with styling but it is a problem to GIS S.E.). Thanks. BTW, +1 for the geojson.io.

Comment: @MagnoC To quote the [JSON specification](http://json.org/) on strings _„A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, […]“_.